# Select a single file history out of Git?

Tags: git

I use Git to keep a version history of config files. For this purpose there are no branches. I keep a ton of these in the same repository, some of which have sensitive data. I need to zip up and send a history of a *single file* out of this repository to a vendor to diagnose a problem. How do I do so?

Comment: `git filter-branch` can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `git log -p <file>` generates all the patches used for a file.
- `git blame <file>` shows what revision and author last modified each line of a file. [docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-blame)
- `gitk <file>` gives you better visualization of the changes. [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk)